# How to compile Innosetup script in Silent mode?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to **compile** the innosetup script in **Silent mode using command prompt.**
Using this method, i can compile the innosetup script **"Compil32 /cc "mypath\myscript.iss"**
Then compilation happened successfully,but innosetup script window opening during compilation, i don't want to open the innosetup scrip window during compilation,How can i proceed that using the below link
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc

In that link they provide "/Q" command line, but i don't know where to use the command line for silent compilation.
Any help????

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't use `Compil32`, which is the GUI compiler. Use `ISCC.EXE` instead, which is the command-line compiler and supports a `/q` switch:

```
iscc /q mypath\myscript.iss
```

For more info on what command-line options are available, just run `iscc /?` from a command prompt.

Comment: Where can one find `iscc.exe`? It doesn't appear to be included in the inno setup installs https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php (only the GUI compiler, `Compil32.exe`, appears to be included). According to the github page, https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc,  `isccs.exe` is still one of the 6 projects in inno setup compiler, however, I'm wondering if it can be downloaded somewhere, rather than having to clone the repo and build it manually?

Comment: @bikz: It's part of Inno Setup, at least in Inno Setup 5 (the only version I have on the computer I'm on).  I have both compil32.exe and iscc.exe in the root of the Inno Setup 5 folder. Did you follow the link in the other answer below?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does not appear to be included in Inno Setup 6, at least none of the versions I tried. I tried some old releases of Inno Setup 6 in addition to the latest stable, but it was not there. I went ahead and got Inno Setup 5, and it IS included in there - thank you for the heads up.

Comment: After uninstalling and re-installing Inno setup 6, `iscc.exe` does appear to be included. I am not certain what happened during my previous installs such that the download didn't appear to complete; the gui compiler worked fine for me so I hadn't noticed an issue. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: With Version 6, I found it located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6". Put that path in your %PATH% environment variable to run it without specifying the full path.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question with the reference as below link "http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc", and the answer is,
"ISCC.exe /Q "mypath\myscript.iss"